# Interrupt `mv` command by ctrl+c, and disk space is lost

Tags: 18.04, disk, disk-usage, mv, interrupts

To transfer large amount of data, I used `mv` from the first HDD called `/KRX` to other HDD called `/data_tmp`.

But I interrupted the `mv` process using `Ctrl+C`, and I fill `/KRX` with other data.

Then when I inspect the disk space via `df -h` I have the following

```bsh
df -h
```

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb        7.3T  7.2T     0 100% /KRX
/dev/sda1       3.6T  3.4T   46G  99% /data_tmp
```

When I remove or move some files in `/KRX`, still it shows `Avail 0` whereas `Used` decreased from `7.2T` to `7.1T` as follows:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb        7.3T  7.1T     0 100% /KRX
/dev/sda1       3.6T  3.4T   46G  99% /data_tmp
```

So how to resolve the zero `Avail`?

I used Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

I just [set zero reserved-blocks as follows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252926/why-doesnt-deleting-files-increase-available-space):

```bsh
sudo tune2fs -m 0 /dev/sda
```

Then `df -h` shows

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb        7.3T  7.1T  132G  99% /KRX
```